# Conditionally remove undefined from type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type this `getConfig` function such that TypeScript knows that if a config element has `required: true` then the `value` will not be undefined (because it would throw an error).

This is where I've got to. My type tests pass, but there's still a type error on the last `return` which I don't understand:

```
const config = {
  FOO: {
    required: true,
    value: process.env.FOO,
  },
  BAR: {
    required: false,
    value: process.env.BAR,
  },
} as const;

type Config = typeof config;

function getConfig<K extends keyof Config>(
  key: K,
): Config[K]["required"] extends true
  ? Exclude<Config[K]["value"], undefined>
  : Config[K]["value"] {
  const configElement = config[key];
  if (configElement.required) {
    if (configElement.value === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`Config value ${key} is required but not set`);
    }

    return configElement.value as Exclude<Config[K]["value"], undefined>;
  }

  return configElement.value;
}

// TESTS

const foo: string = getConfig('FOO');
// @ts-expect-error: Type  string | undefined  is not assignable to type  string
const bar: string = getConfig('BAR');
```

Error:

```
Type '"" | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ readonly FOO: { readonly required: true; readonly value: "" | undefined; }; readonly BAR: { readonly required: false; readonly value: "" | undefined; }; }[K]["required"] extends true ? Exclude<...> : { ...; }[K]["value"]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ readonly FOO: { readonly required: true; readonly value: "" | undefined; }; readonly BAR: { readonly required: false; readonly value: "" | undefined; }; }[K]["required"] extends true ? Exclude<...> : { ...; }[K]["value"]'.(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtiYBrACgJ0QUwhAomANxgF4YBZAQygAsA6NCsAExDgAoBKGAPhgAZaAVhgB+GAHJxMAFwwArs0wAzAJZhMTANwAobaEix9qgOYkYAb20wYAMQDyd2ZevW0mAI5yVbprKho5TAAaKxcCCgAbQNkEZHQsHHwCEOsAXxSYACEAQQAlJ1DXDy8fWSVIiGDCmHCozBjEVAxgbDxCDPTtVJgKCBh9aF0oAE8AB0wYAGFwEzMR8ZAlfpmVYx1tJQVgKBVwGGNMKGmwEwAeAGkYTAAPKExmPqRMYcWpleNuNlCn4dlzkI4smOJgA2ucALoggBEbk83g0UPBV1u9yYfX8gVCYlw12AUSYmFOwNWYMhUNqgURQXkilU6iY3FCQPepOhFMwiIsoQGhneuAimDg91gpCMJJ+4J01hUSzYYuM-MFwvoxXhTC4zhcMpgcr5AqFYCgtHZJGIpAUBLpGg11WsNAwAHcYOonbg0Bg0GwAAbE0wmgAk5h+3RUfVhJQ0MAARnJYGAQLBKlAvRwpS5UroXDA3FA5GgwMsTqtFQajSbejAcXi5ASiSyIWzIpTwdSLco1BpuGmM6Ec3mC-KS8r2ToewB6McwAAquAAylPZ7oeTAlCAQLJoGg1KZSAcju82OJ7HZxKntBOYAABKAQAC0N3G23v7pAaFkU7GEwABZvtzAAD40paHZMF+MChs6CY9DgqxgBQUYCjAUAgEhn4wD+-jbno4DQNGFBvjAv5gDu+yHL6h45Lkp6aEAA)

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/wX188N should do the trick

Comment: That works but it's error-prone as you must remember to sync the type casts and the `required` value. I wonder if we can do better.

Comment: The only type assertions are on the result of the runtime random determined type. There are ways you could probably restructure the program generally to avoid this but there's no way for the compiler to know the actual result type of the ternary expression and thus eliminate the Union cases

Comment: Tamlyn, *functions with conditional return type always require return type cast*, as the variable of generic-dependent type is not expressable

Comment: So just `return as any`

Comment: Consider useng premapped type rather then conditionsl return: https://tsplay.dev/wO29yW